# 乗り換え verbal noun does not take -する, instead 乗り換える?

Tags: verbs, nouns

Is anyone able to explain why the verbal noun 乗り換え does not take -suru, but instead becomes 乗り換える?

Cheers,

Luke

Comment: I can find examples of people using 乗り換えする, but you seem to already know where 乗り換え came from (when you called it a verbal noun), so you're not surprised that 乗り換える exists right?

Answer (score 1):

乗り換え is a noun coming from the verb 乗り換える.

What you're trying to do is a bit like taking the English noun 'transformation' and turning it into the verb 'to transformation' instead of using the source verb 'to transform'.